# Vector space subspace problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S$ be a non - empty set and $F$ be a field. Let $C(S,F)$ denote the set of all functions $f\in \mathcal F(S,F)$ such that $f(s)=0$ for all but a finite number of elements of $S$. Prove that $C(S,F)$ is a subspace of $\mathcal F(S,F)$

My progress:
I have shown that if $f,g\in C(S,F)$ and $a\in F$ then $f+g\in C(S,F)$ and $af\in C(S,F)$.

I need to show that the zero element is in $C(S,F)$. What is the zero element here and how do I show it's in $C(S,F)$

Comment: What is $F(S,F)$?

Comment: I don't know, it's not defined in the problem :/ The first F is the script F though. I don't know how to do scriptF in TeX, sorry :/

Comment: for script, try \mathcal. Maybe it is the set of all functions from $S$ to $F$? Does this make sense based on the context?

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me, but maybe I'm missing something? And thanks! :)

Comment: If $\mathcal C (S,F)$ is the set of functions from $S$ to $F$ that take are nonzero on only finitely many elements of $S$, then it's hard for me to think of something else for $\mathcal F(S,F)$ to be. However, perhaps you can find a definitive answer elsewhere in your book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If $\mathcal F(S,F)$ denotes the set of all functions from $S$ to $F$ and $e \in \mathcal F(S,F)$ is an identity element, then for any $ f \in \mathcal F(S,F)$ we must have $e+f=f+e=f$. Hence, for any $x \in S$:

$$f(x)=(f+e)(x)=f(x)+e(x).$$

From this, what can you deduce about the value of $e(x)$ at any $x \in S$?

Comment: $e(x)=0$ at any $x$?

Comment: @Diya this sounds right to me. Does this make sense to you, and do you see why $e \in \mathcal C(S,F)$?

Comment: Well, $e(x)=0$ for all $x\in S$, so $e(x)=0$ for all but finite (here, none) $x\in S$, and hence $e\in \mathcal C(S,F)$, right?

Comment: Exactly. Hope this clarifies things!

Comment: It did, thank you :) One more thing, basically this zero function can work as identity of any set of functions, right?

Comment: @Diya You need some sort of algebraic structure on the codomain for this to make sense. Given an abelian group $(G,+)$ and a set $S$, the set of functions from $S$ to $G$, which I'll denote $\mathcal F (S,G)$, inherits a natural group structure: $f+g$ is the function defined by $(f+g)(s)= f(s)+g(s)$. The identity element of $\mathcal F(S,G)$ will be the function which sense every element to the identity of $G$. ...

Comment: In your case, $G=F$ is a field, so $\mathcal F(S,F)$ is naturally a vector space. (That is, given $f \in \mathcal F(S,F)$ and $\lambda \in F$, we can define $\lambda f$ by the formula $(\lambda f)(x)=\lambda\cdot f(x)$ for any $x\in S$). Note that the $0$ of $\mathcal F(S,F)$ as a vectorspace is the identity element of $\mathcal F (S,F)$ considered as a group; so the more general statement for groups implies that the zero element of $\mathcal F(S,F)$ as a vector space is given by the zero function.

Answer (score 1):

The zero element is the function that is constantly zero: $f(s)=0$ for all $s$ in $S$.  This function satisfies the condition that $f$ be zero except on all but a finite number of elements of $S$ and so zero is in $C(S,F)$.